# RStudio vim editing mode to pick up .vimrc file

Tags: vim, rstudio

In RStudio, there is a vim editing mode, under global options -> code.

But I have a .vimrc file that I normally use, and would like to pull in those preferences.

How can I get RStudio to pick it up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, no chance.

Comment: The "vim" mode in RStudio is not Vim; the chances of it using your `vimrc` are very very close to 0.

Comment: somewhat related to your question, I thought to share it. I came to know about [**Vim-R-Tmux: An Integrated Working Environment for R**](http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r/vim-r). I guess configuring this environment would allow you using same .vimrc